# Add row clearfix after evry three column does any one know how to make it using view?

Tags: views

```
<div class="blog-categories-warp">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row clearfix">
             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                 <h3>General</h3>
                    <ul class="archive-list">
                     <li>
                         <a href="#">Diam mus suspendisse eu sed in senectus ut a cum.<span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                         <a href="#">Litora augue parturient suspendisse ullamcorper fermentum velit aliquet augue ullamcorper lobortis.<span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="more-in-blog"><a href="#">More in General</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                 <h3>Selerisque sceler</h3>
                    <ul class="archive-list">
                     <li>
                         <a href="#">Diam mus suspendisse eu sed in senectus ut a cum.<span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                         <a href="#">Litora augue parturient suspendisse ullamcorper ferrtis.<span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="more-in-blog"><a href="#">More in General</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                 <h3>Hac ad sagittis</h3>
                    <ul class="archive-list">
                     <li>
                         <a href="#">Diam mus suspendisse eu sed in senectus ut a cum.<span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                         <a href="#">A ultricies litora habitasse eget condimen <span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                         <a href="#">Scelerisque parturient vestibulum scelerisqu. <span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                         <a href="#">Litora augue parturient suspendisse ullamcorper ferrtis.<span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="more-in-blog"><a href="#">More in General</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row clearfix">             
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                 <h3>Selerisque sceler</h3>
                    <ul class="archive-list">
                     <li>
                         <a href="#">Diam mus suspendisse eu sed in senectus ut a cum.<span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                         <a href="#">A ultricies litora habitasse eget condimen <span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                         <a href="#">Scelerisque parturient vestibulum scelerisque dictum a jisse gravida curae at. <span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                         <a href="#">Scelerisque parturient vestibulum scelerisque dictumt fringilla. <span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                         <a href="#">Litora augue parturient suspendisse ullamcorper ferrtis.<span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="more-in-blog"><a href="#">More in General</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                 <h3>Hac ad sagittis</h3>
                    <ul class="archive-list">
                     <li>
                         <a href="#">Diam mus suspendisse eu sed in senectus ut a cum.<span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                       <li>
                         <a href="#">Litora augue parturient suspendisse ullamcorper ferrtis.<span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="more-in-blog"><a href="#">More in General</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                 <h3>General</h3>
                    <ul class="archive-list">
                    <li>
                         <a href="#">Diam mus suspendisse eu sed in senectus ut a cum.<span>on 24 April, 2016</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="more-in-blog"><a href="#">More in General</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to make structure of html like this using view 
and i also make views but i can't add `<div class="row clearfix">` at the every third column can any one help me out?

I'm using Drupal 7, Views 3

Comment: Akil, could you please include what you have tried, what version of Drupal and Views you are using. Perhaps, even, what kind of solution would work for you (code, template, etc).

Comment: Yes i mentioned it

Comment: Sorry to give you lake of information 
i tried to make template of views-view-list.tpl.php and tried to add class using prifix and suffix variable which is created in template.php but i cant add that after three column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not what you thought you'd get, but here's a CSS selector that can do this fix for you, no preprocessing needed:

```
.blog-categories-warp > .container > .row:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
}
```

> Note: As of writing, 97.22% of the browsers in the world would support this CSS selector: http://caniuse.com/#search=nth

I'm interested because your code given doesn't actually give us three rows. So I had to add some to make sure my CSS worked. It does.

[image: example of css working]

Here's the CSS snippet that adds bootstrap's clearfix hack:

```
.blog-categories-warp > .container > .row:nth-child(3):before,
.blog-categories-warp > .container > .row:nth-child(3):after {
  content: " "; /* 1 */
  display: table; /* 2 */
}
.blog-categories-warp > .container > .row:nth-child(3):after { clear: both; }
/* For IE 6/7 only */
.blog-categories-warp > .container > .row:nth-child(3) {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

And here's a working example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNzyNw

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply 
the problem is if i don't add the row clearfix after three column then if more node are listed in li structure then it breakdown the structure